# Class and scope in ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, scope

Im building an ember application consuming a couple of web services. And I'm trying to pass a class object throw the config/environment file doing this:

```
var myclass = require('myclass-package');

var ENV = {
    APP: {
       MY_OBJ_CLASS: new myclass({
                        //CONSTRUCTOR PARAMS...
                        PROP1: "HELLO"
                     }) 
    }
}
```

In my ember app/controllers I'm doing this:

```
import ENV from '../config/environment';
var obj1 = ENV.APP.MY_OBJ_CLASS;
```

I can see that the object is instantiated if I console.log the class object but when I try to access to the properties and functions, I can't and I get back this error:

```
var data = obj1.my_function_class({param1:1});
console.log(data)
TypeError: obj1.my_function_class is not a function
```

But the function exist...
What is the way to access to my class properties and functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`config/environment.js` is a special file. It is executed in Node, then serialized to be made available for the browser app.

You should not store any functionality in that file.

Put your class into a proper Ember module. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, that could be a service, a model, an util, etc.

Provide more details on your original problem, not your attempted solution. See http://xyproblem.info .

Comment: That's true, my friend, thank you very much. I just got what I want using services.